Pandas Persistent Sorting
I have a text file with 8 columns
# 0.y[m] 1.uy[m_e*c] 2.x[m] 3.ux[m_ec] 4.z[m] 5.uz[m_ec] 6.w 7.ID.
In this file, the first line is commented with # and there is no label for the data columns. I import this file in a data frame using
data = pd.DataFrame(pd.read_csv("file.txt", sep='\t', comment='#', header=None));
and diplaying it I see:

Now, I need to sort ascending for the last column so I use index 7 and this code line
dataS = data.sort_values(7);
and sorting works because now I see

but sorting is not persistent because
data[7][0] = 24641553
and
dataS[7][0] = 24641553
I need to use the sorted data frame one row after the other, exactly in the sorted order, so my code will rely on a for loop which uses dataS[7][i] where i = 0, 1, 2, ...
Code is below.
import pandas as pd;
data = pd.DataFrame(pd.read_csv("file.txt", sep='\t', comment='#', header=None));
dataS = data.sort_values(7);

Sample text file looks like this:
#0.y[m] 1.uy[m_e*c] 2.x[m] 3.ux[m_ec] 4.z[m] 5.uz[m_ec] 6.w 7.ID
4.800773e-06    5.825619e+00    9.693396e-06    1.732705e+00    1.068944e-05    -3.532225e+00   1.255580e+04    24641553
4.359847e-06    1.275340e+01    9.564333e-06    -3.591681e-01   9.690643e-06    7.398885e+00    1.255580e+04    18676620

My problem is that I don't know how to cycle on the sorted data frame labeled by dataS here. Can anyone help please? Thanks!

Can you please provide a reproducible example and your full code? Otherwise it is not clear what the issue is here.

The problem is not that the sorting isn't persistent, it's that it's also sorting the index:
dataS = data.sort_values(7)

          0          1        2  ...         5        6         7
1  0.000004  12.753400  0.00001  ...  7.398885  12555.8  18676620
0  0.000005   5.825619  0.00001  ... -3.532225  12555.8  24641553

If you want to sort only the values, but not the index, use ignore_index=True:
dataS = data.sort_values(7, ignore_index=True)

          0          1        2  ...         5        6         7
0  0.000004  12.753400  0.00001  ...  7.398885  12555.8  18676620
1  0.000005   5.825619  0.00001  ... -3.532225  12555.8  24641553

dataS[7][0] will output:
18676620


You need to reset the index after sorting.
dataS = dataS.reset_index(drop=True)

will do the trick.
On a side note, take a look into this post about iterating over DataFrames, especially the second answer: How can I iterate over rows in a Pandas DataFrame
